# How to Rename FolderNames and FileNames with matching strings Recursively

Tags: c#, string, winforms, directory

My application generates files in the following directory structure

```
FolderMatchALeve1
-FileMatchALevel2_A.cs
-FileMatchALevel2_B.cs
-FolderMatchALevel2
--FileMatchALevel3_A.txt
--FileMatchALevel3_B.txt
```

I am looking for a way to rename the directory structure, with the following change – Change **“MatchA”** to **“AMatch”**.

So the result should look like so after executing the program:

```
FolderAMatchLeve1
-FileAMatchLevel2_A.cs
-FileAMatchLevel2_B.cs
-FolderAMatchLevel2
--FileAMatchLevel3_A.txt
--FileAMatchLevel3_B.txt
```

So far in my quest to find a solution, I have been unsuccessful. Please help me find a solution to this.

I need this solution in C# Winforms because of maintaining a legacy product at our company.

Edit:

**Additional Information**

1. I need to make this change each time someone runs our program.
2. I need to do this to 3350 files

**Question Summary:**

In short, while recursively(or iteratively) going through each directory, I want it to rename files whose names match with matching strings and then after coming out, rename the directory, if it too has a name matching the string (for all partial or complete matches).

Comment: What about [`File.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) and [`Directory.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx)?

Comment: let me read this. Do note that I have 3350 files

Comment: How often do you need to do this? If just once, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It does not matter if you have 2 or unlimited files it is just a matter of time but not how to process it. And it does not matter if you are working with WinForms or WPF

Comment: i need to do this once per project.

Comment: let me add the above 2 information to the question.

Comment: I am looking for a working code snippet if it is not too much trouble.

Comment: @SirRufo, I dont yet know the exact library difference between various C# based solutions, I added that tag so that I get a solution which works in Winforms. Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and Dirty (but working)

```
public static class DirectoryRenamer
{
    public static void RenameDirectoryTree( string path, Func<string, string> renamingRule )
    {
        var di = new DirectoryInfo( path );
        RenameDirectoryTree( di, renamingRule );
    }

    public static void RenameDirectoryTree( DirectoryInfo directory, Func<string, string> renamingRule )
    {
        InternalRenameDirectoryTree( directory, renamingRule );

        var currentName = directory.Name;
        var newName = renamingRule( currentName );
        if ( currentName != newName )
        {
            var newDirname = Path.Combine( directory.Parent.FullName, newName );
            directory.MoveTo( newDirname );
        }
    }

    static void InternalRenameDirectoryTree( DirectoryInfo di, Func<string, string> renamingRule )
    {
        foreach ( var item in di.GetFileSystemInfos() )
        {
            var subdir = item as DirectoryInfo;
            if ( subdir != null )
            {
                InternalRenameDirectoryTree( subdir, renamingRule );

                var currentName = subdir.Name;
                var newName = renamingRule( currentName );
                if ( currentName != newName )
                {
                    var newDirname = Path.Combine( subdir.Parent.FullName, newName );
                    subdir.MoveTo( newDirname );
                }
            }

            var file = item as FileInfo;
            if ( file != null )
            {
                var currentName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( file.Name );
                var newName = renamingRule( currentName );
                if ( currentName != newName )
                {
                    var newFilename = Path.Combine( file.DirectoryName, newName + file.Extension );
                    file.MoveTo( newFilename );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sample usage

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        DirectoryRenamer.RenameDirectoryTree( 
            @"C:\Test\FolderMatchALevel", 
            name => name.Replace( "MatchA", "AMatch" ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really good. It worked in 2 out of 3 folders. I am getting error in one saying it is being used by another process, even though I am running the program after a fresh boot.

Comment: Which one ... I guess the folder you pass in path argument. It is locked whenever you have any applications current directory on that path. Seems your application is on there

Comment: I will write back when I root cause the issue. But for my case, it is replacing the part where it matters the most. Thank you Sir Rufo. I am really happy that people like you are out there (^_^)

Comment: I was getting the problem because I was using stream reader and not closing the handle. The problem is now resolved after I enclosed my code in a using block. The problem i was facing was not from your code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using wildcards I was once able to change the file-endings of a number of files using basic move command. But these changes might be a bit beyond it.

But overall this is just trivial recursion over folders using [Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) Class or one of the other ones.
Pseudo code goes like this:

1. List all Directories in the current directory.
2. Recursively call this function again for all the sub-directories
3. Iterate over all the files in this directory
4. Rename this directory.

Note that the "proper" way to do renaming is the move command. Indeed there is no technical difference between move and rename on the same disk.

You also may want to put Nr. 4 on a Boolean Switch. Name one of the Parameters "DirectoryRename". Let it default to true. Hand it in false on the first call and do not use it for recursive calls.